# Postgresql - select entity with distinct @ManyToOne column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 entities - `Query` and `QueryExecution`.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "db_test")
data class Query(
        @NotNull
        var text: String,
        var name: String?,
) : AbstractEntity()


@Entity
@Table(schema = "db_test")
data class QueryExecution(
        @ManyToOne
        @NotNull
        @JoinColumn(name = "query")
        var query: ManualQuery,

        var status: QueryStatus
) : AbstractEntity()
```

Query:

```
|    id      | text                   | name     |
|:-----------|-----------------------:|:--------:|
| 100        | select * from b        | b        |
| 200        | select * from c        | c        |
| 300        | select * from d        | d        |
```

Query-execution:

```
|    id      | query      | status     |
|:-----------|------------|------------|
| 100        | 100        | NEW        |  
| 200        | 200        | EXECUTED   |
| 300        | 200        | EXECUTED   | 
| 400        | 200        | EXECUTED   |
| 500        | 300        | EXECUTED   |
| 600        | 200        | REFECTED   |
| 700        | 100        | EXECUTED   |
| 800        | 300        | EXECUTED   |
| 800        | 200        | EXECUTED   |
```

How to fetch `query_execution` such that it contains only a single record of each one the queries?

#### result (order by id)

```
|    id      | query      | status   |
|:-----------|------------|----------|
| 100        | 100        | NEW      |
| 200        | 200        | EXECUTED |
| 500        | 300        | EXECUTED |
```

Comment: Have you tried with UNION?

Comment: `select distinct on (query) * from QueryExecution order by query, id, status` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

There at least two ways to select entities with distinct @ManyToOne column.

#### 1.

```
with a as (
    select max(id) as id, query from query_execution group by query
) select me.* from query_execution qe join a on a.id = qe.id;
```

#### 2

```
select distinct on (query) * from query_execution  order by query, id
```